# Getting a simple javascript to work in Linux that i created in Windows

Tags: javascript, cross-platform

So I have been dabbling in making a script for phone games using .csv files as the data sources. They work fine in windows XP all the way through Windows 8. I use this in Firefox w Imacros/Greasemonkey installed. I then decided to try in Linux Mint 14 and set it all up using latest version of FF and all the applications that go with it. The following is the script that we(others and I, I have been chosen as the guinea pig) when i run it it just freezes. No error or anything FF freezes and becomes un responsive and i have to force close appliction. I wanted to get some feedback on possible reasons and maybe some direction on fixes for this if there is one available.

```
var numberOfUrls = 1591
var code = prompt("JUST CLICK OK DATA WILL OUTPUT UNDER iMacros/Downloads/extract.csv.")
while(true){
for(var i=1;i<numberOfUrls;i++){
var macro = "CODE: "
macro+= "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES"+"\n"
macro+= "SET !REPLAYSPEED fast"+"\n"
macro+= "SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1"+"\n"
macro+= "SET !DATASOURCE ww_fresh_urls2.csv"+"\n"
macro+= "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1" +"\n"
macro+= "SET !VAR1 "+code+"\n"
macro+= "SET !LOOP "+i+"\n"
macro+= "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}"+"\n"
macro+= "URL GOTO={{!COL1}}"+"\n"
macro+= "WAIT SECONDS=.5"+"\n"
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:profileName EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n";
macro+= "WAIT SECONDS=.5"+"\n"
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:codeCode EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n";
macro+= "WAIT SECONDS=.5"+"\n"
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:levelFrontTopArea EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n";
macro+= "WAIT SECONDS=.5"+"\n"
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:cashCurrent EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n";
macro+= "WAIT SECONDS=.5"+"\n"
macro += "TAG POS=5 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n";
macro+= "WAIT SECONDS=.5"+"\n"
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:home" + "\n"
macro+= "WAIT SECONDS=.5"+"\n"
macro+= "URL GOTO=http://wwar.storm8.com/setting.php?selectedTab=storm8"+"\n"
macro+= "WAIT SECONDS=.5"+"\n"
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=TD FORM=ACTION:/setting.php?  formNonce=*&setTab1Badge=1&*                                                               ATTR=CLASS:usernameText EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n";
macro+= "WAIT SECONDS=.5"+"\n"
macro += "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=*" + "\n";
iimPlay(macro)
}
}
```

Comment: .iim is imacros format. It allows the .js to run in iMacros the diff being .js uses a "loop" variable command where .iim has the loop as part of the imacros function

Comment: yes, its a user script script ran in iMacros with greasemonkey on Firefox 19.

Comment: String concatenation is not something cheap.

Comment: ASI is not meant to be relied on either.

Answer (score 5):

> when i run it it just freezes. No error or anything FF freezes and becomes un responsive and i have

Well here's your problem:

```
 while(true){
```

Infinite loops block the browser. You did something really bad and now bad things happen.

Do something good. I have no idea what you're trying to do, but unless this is a state machine you shouldn't have an infinite loop.

Comment: not a state machine...I am pulling the data off of a phone game account and downloading it to a .csv for purposes of tracking stats. no big state secrets here.

Comment: Sounds like you don't need an infinite loop.

Comment: I limit the "loops" by using the very first line for the number of URLS listed in the datasource .csv. it should cycle through then extract that to a target .csv named "extract" .

Comment: Like i said in windows it runs fine....no problem...however windows uses alot of resources and i wanted to try this in Linux and see if it would run more efficiently in Linux...however, it just stops.

Comment: Windows is just fine on resources.  I'll wager *this script* is what's having issues.  :P

Comment: Why do you have the `while(true)` loop at all? I'm not familiar with imacros, but `while(true){for...` seems useless, redundant, and error-prone.

Comment: that particular lnes refers to the datasource file so when it encounters and "empty cell it will basically error out the entire line to show and end to the list of stats.

Comment: where do you ever break out of the while loop? as far as I can see you will never because there is no break. `true` will always be true.

Comment: @GeorgeVeitl: `while (true) { for (var i=1; i<numberOfUrls; ++i) { ... } }` loops from 1 to `numberOfUrls - 1`, *over and over again, forever*.  That is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: actually, it in this script no we dont want it unending, in our other scripts we do. my main concern is the fact this runs fin in windows but not in Linux. I can pull that line out and try it that way and see what happens.

Comment: @GeorgeVeitl: There is almost no case where you really want an infinite loop in Javascript.  Since JS is asynchronous, it doesn't wait for much of anything; it just fires off a "hey, browser, do this" message for anything that would otherwise involve waiting, and the browser generally doesn't even start the task til JS returns control to it...so in an infinite loop, you don't do anything but spin your wheels while you wait for an event that never happens. For most cases where you might want an infinite loop, what you really want is a callback to handle an event and set up the next "iteration".

Comment: recursion is so recursive it's almost like it's a recurring block?! `function foo() { .. some stuffs ... setTimeout(foo, 1); // 1 tests better than 0 on some browsers }`